# Does anyone know how to converter I can use in Xamarin forms that will do an OR between two bool parameters?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here is the situation that I have:

```xml
   <Stack IsVisible="{Binding IsGood}" >
      <Label Text="Is Good or Okay" />
   </Stack>
   <Stack IsVisible="{Binding IsOkay}" >
      <Label Text="Is Good or Okay" />
   </Stack>
```

What I would like to do is to somehow code it like this:

```xml
   <Stack IsVisible="{Binding IsGood, IsOkay, Converter={StaticResource ORConverter} }" >
      <Label Text="Is Good or Okay" />
   </Stack>
```

Comment: why not just add a read-only property in your viewmodel that does this?

Comment: Well I have a lot of different cases so ideally if I was able to substitute in a converter or something like that then I wouldn't need to create more properties.

Comment: You want to invoke the PropertyChanged/Converter only if **both** values changed?

Comment: If both values are true then I would like the converter to return true.  If it's possible to make a converter that checks even more params that would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a converter do that. A converter only takes one value. Instead, why not just use a property in the ViewModel which reflects this instead?

```
public bool AorB => A || B;

private bool _a;
public bool A
{
    get => _a;
    set
    {
        _a = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(AorB));
    }
}

private bool _b;
public bool B
{
    get => _b;
    set
    {
        _b = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(AorB));
    }
}
```

Now, if you are using MvvmCross, you could use the [Value Combiners](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/value-combiners) it provides. However, it will only work for MvvmCross's binding descriptions, which would look like:

```
If(Or(A, B), 'true', 'false')
```

That would need you to depend on MvvmCross though and switch to its bindings for these kind of operations.